# Is it possible to stop these faces from rendering?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've started a three.js cube based game and have had some trouble with rendering transparency in blocks.

I'm loading up the blocks from a JSON file, where the structure of each looks like this:

```
{
    'sprite': 'water.png',
    'collides': false,
    'moves': false,
    'transparent': true
}
```

Then creating textures in my renderer from their sprite and transparent value.

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/img/' + 
    _materials[i].sprite);

var properties = {
    map: texture
};

if(_materials[i].transparent) {
    properties.opacity = 0.3;
    properties.transparent = true;
}

materials[i] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(properties);
```

And the previous definition for water, looks like this.

[image: water rendering]

You can see the faces of the other water blocks, through ones that are above and beside them. Is it possible to prevent this from happening?

Comment: you'll want some hidden face elimination so either you don't pass the inner faces to the renderer at all or only render the transparent face closest to the camera

Comment: If it was me, I would simply only render the top faces. Like @ratchetfreak said.

Comment: If you cannot assign individual faces in your cube different materials, you could draw the water in two passes. On the first pass, disable color writes and enable depth writes and on the second pass enable color writes but disable depth writes and use a depth test: `GL_LEQUAL`. This should eliminate all but the top layer of water, though due to the joys of floating-point you might need a small depth offset on one of your passes in order for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest solution is to use multi-materials for CubeGeometry.

Do like this :

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/img/' + 
    _materials[i].sprite);

var properties = {
     map: texture
};
// hidden faces texture with opacity to 0
var hMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xFFFFFF, transparent:true, opacity:0});


if(_materials[i].transparent) {
    properties.opacity = 0.3;
    properties.transparent = true;
}

matWater = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(properties);

var finalMat = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial([ hMat, hMat, matWater, hMat, hMat, hMat]);
// I guess indice 2 is the top face , depend the cube orientation.

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(CubeGeo, finalMat);
```

regards.